# Add device to nest devices list

Tags: firebase, nest-api

I am using sample application control-jquery-master provided on developer.nest.com. I can access first device for e.g. thermostat as written in the code. It shows on the html page http://localhost:8080 with status "INSIDE" and two buttons "UP" arrow and "DOWN" arrow. Now, I want to add my own device instead of "thermostat" something like "mysensor" with different properties that can be set or retrieved. Is it possible to do that? If yes, what are the API, If not does it mean we can only use thermostat, smoke detector sensors which are provided by nest?
My question is how to access and modify the JSON document? Where is it stored?

Best Regards,
Sonal

Comment: are you asking how to put a non-nest device into the nest API?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to add your own sensor(s) to the devices JSON payload is to make use of the Product data read/write permission.

This [Nest API doc](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/resource-use-guide/) outlines the steps necessary to reach a working implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to add more physical Nest devices to an account is by doing so on their site or with their app. You can add virtual devices using their Chrome extension: [Nest Home Simulator](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nest-home-simulator/jmcapoebgeaabepohkchkldlfhchkega)